# regarding using a c program for converting csv file to a specific format

Tags: c, libsvm

I am trying to use the convert.c, which is provided on libsvm website, to convert the csv file to libsvm data format. But I never use C and the website does not provide any information on how to use this program. Can I get any hint from here? The following is the code. Many thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char buf[10000000];
float feature[100000];

int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
FILE *fp;

if(argc!=2) { fprintf(stderr,"Usage %s filename\n",argv[0]); }
if((fp=fopen(argv[1],"r"))==NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"Can't open input file %s\n",argv[1]);
}
while(fscanf(fp,"%[^\n]\n",buf)==1)
{
    int i=0,j;
    char *p=strtok(buf,",");

    feature[i++]=atof(p);

    while((p=strtok(NULL,",")))
        feature[i++]=atof(p);

    //      --i;
    /*
    if ((int) feature[i]==1)
        printf("-1 ");
    else
        printf("+1 ");
    */
    //      printf("%f ", feature[1]);
    printf("%d ", (int) feature[0]);
    for(j=1;j<i;j++)
        printf(" %d:%f",j,feature[j]);
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Can you describe how you are trying to use the program and what problems you are having or errors you are seeing.

Comment: And you might want a `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` right after that error message about failure to open the file, or you're destined to crash regardless. `fscanf()` doesn't exactly embrace `NULL` file pointers very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find information about how to use it here:

```
if(argc!=2) { fprintf(stderr,"Usage %s filename\n",argv[0]); }
if((fp=fopen(argv[1],"r"))==NULL)
{
   fprintf(stderr,"Can't open input file %s\n",argv[1]);
}
```

So you need to provide 2 arguments, and one is `program name`, which is `argv[0]`, `argv[1]` is your input file name.

I guess you should do: (firstly, compile the code into an exe file)
then from command line, go the exe file directory, type:

```
programname filename
```

in order to use their code. While `programname` is the conversion program name.

My guess is that the code will read your csv file and extract all features of a data set that can be used for SVM classification.

Comment: Thanks,just as you said, this program is going to read one csv file and output a txt file with special format. One more question, I have linux box running ubuntu. If I want to compile this c program, how can I do that, or do i have to use any specific parameters?

Comment: @user2283247 if this is just a single .c file, you can use gcc to compile it. for example: gcc conver.c -o convert. then after you put your input file at the same directory of the source file, at the terminal you do: ./convert filename. It should run.

Comment: @user2283247 have you tried, does it work? If you have multiple source files, you may need to use makefile or simply do gcc *.cpp -o convert to generate exe file (if all source files are under same directory).

Comment: I compiled convert.c successfully into convert   Then I run the following command, convert test.csv   The error message is like "invalid drive specification"