# How to make convert.c run?

Tags: c, arduino, libsvm

I'm about to use convert.c in converting the csv file from an arduino to a libsvm format which is suggested in the libsvm page but I dont know how to make it run.

Can someone give me an example on how to make it work.

Comment: Are you trying to run convert.c on the arduino or on a desktop machine? If the latter, which OS is the machine running?

Comment: This previous SO question had one answer before the question was closed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019581/regarding-using-a-c-program-for-converting-csv-file-to-a-specific-format

Comment: Im trying to run c on a desktop machine. Im using windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Okay first of all you have to compile the convert.c file in order to get an executable .exe file. Once you are done with that step you run the .exe program and you are done. Note that compilation process depends on what OS you are running. In Windows OS you can use Dev-C++ to compile and run your source code F9 is compile i think and F10 run, not so sure though. If you run Linux you have to download a compiler first and then proceed to the compilation of your source code.This tutorial here might be helpful.
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-compile-and-run-c-cplusplus-code-in-linux/